# Progress bar with 9 different symbols

Tags: python, progress-bar, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and want to display xp-bar with emojis. (in this example I have substituted the emojis for ascii-characters) The bar is 10 emojis long, with 3 different types of pieces. Left-side, Middle and Right-side. Each of these can be Empty, Half-full and full. My current solution uses a lot of if-else statements, and is pretty messy overall.

Here is my solution at the moment. i is the state the bar is: 0 being empty, 20 being full. This code prints all the bars from 0 to 20.

```
def main():
for i in range(21):
    if i in [0,1]:
        if i == 0:
            print("[00", end="")
        else:
            print("[X0", end="")
        for x in range(8):
            print("00", end="")
        print("00]", end="")
    elif i in [19,20]:
        print("[XX", end="")
        for x in range(8):
            print("XX", end="")
        if i == 19:
            print("X0]", end="")
        else:
            print("XX]", end="")
    else:
        print("[XX", end="")
        for x in range(i//2-1):
            print("XX", end="")
        if i % 2 == 1:
            print("X0", end="")
        for x in range(8-(i % 2)-(i//2-1)):
            print("00", end="")
        print("00]", end="")
    print("")
```

Output:

```
[....................]
[X...................]
[XX..................]
[XXX.................]
[XXXX................]
[XXXXX...............]
[XXXXXX..............]
[XXXXXXX.............]
[XXXXXXXX............]
[XXXXXXXXX...........]
[XXXXXXXXXX..........]
[XXXXXXXXXXX.........]
[XXXXXXXXXXXX........]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXX.......]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXX......]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.....]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX....]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.]
[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]
```

My question is: is there an easier, smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this for ya, if you read through it hopefully you will get a better understanding of the premise of automation which python is all about!

```
def squareBrackets(string:str):
    newString = "[" + string + "]"
    return newString

def fillGaps(string:str):
    amountToFill = 20 - len(string)
    return string + "." * amountToFill # If you multiply strings, it will just make a bunch of them over and over in the same string. So "hello"*3 would give you "hellohellohello"

def main():
    for i in range(21):
        string = "X"*i
        print(squareBrackets(fillGaps(string)))
```

Comment: Pretty much what I commented earlier, The progress bar will not be made of ascii-characters and rather discord emojis. I appreciate the effort tho! I have 9 different discord emojis each representing unique piece of the progress bar. "[X." for example represents left side of the progress bar, which is half full and I have made own custom emoji for that.

Answer (score 0):

I should create a function that creates a progress bar (given how full the progress bar is, and the size):

```
    def progress_bar(full, length_progress_bar):
        # Adds a '[' then for how full the progress bar is adds '*', 
        # then add '.' for the remaining bit, then adds ']'
        progress_bar_ = f"[{'*' * full}{'.' * (length_progress_bar - full)}]"
        return progress_bar_

    width_progress_bar = 20
    for full in range(0, width_progress_bar + 1):
        print(f'{full}: {progress_bar(full, width_progress_bar)}')
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the effort for providing a full function! This is not the solution I am looking for though. What I am trying to do is have the progress bar use 9 different emojis. I only used ascii-characters in my example because here I can't really use the discord emojis. This function is for discord.py bot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program I wrote. Hopefully it helps:

```
def main():
   for i in range(21):
       print("[" + "X" * i + "0" * (20-1) + "]")
```

Comment: Did you read the question mate? I am dealing with custom emojis and the ascii-characters were just an example.

Comment: Then you can try making a list with all of the Emojis, then using .index() to access using the range.